# ActiveRecord Change Primary Key Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails with active record. Right now I have a standard auto_increment, int primary key in a table. Is there a way I can change the format of this key to "AA0000#" where # is the auto_incremented number?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to change your id column to a VARCHAR? Seems like this is something you can also solve in your application with a simple method on your model?